# Asking bash to produce completion answer for a command?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I'm writing a CLI utility called [envset](https://metacpan.org/pod/envset), which has this usage: `envset [ENVSET-OPTIONS] [SETNAME] [--] [CMD] [ARGS]...`.
It basically runs a command with a set of environment variables defined in a config file (there's already an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/envset) with the same name, but I'm implementing my utility in Perl with a different feature set).

I want to provide tab completion for `envset`. The completion is handled by a shell function `_envset`. It would be nice in the case like below (`^` denotes the location of cursor when `Tab` is pressed):

```
% envset mycolors -- ls -^
```

`_envset` can return the completion answers for `ls` instead (so, return a list of possible ls command-line options). Is there an easy way I can ask bash to return them for me?

Otherwise, I'd have to do something like the following in `_envset` (which is not perfect but should be good enough for most cases):

1. parse the output of `complete` to find an entry that describes how a command (in the above example, `ls`) is completed. If there is none, find the entry with `-D` (default handler).
2. if the command is completed by function (-F), call that function (after setting COMP_WORDS and COMP_CWORD appropriately). Return the COMPREPLY from the function.
3. if the command is completed by external command (-C), run the command (after setting COMP_LINE and COMP_POINT appropriately). Capture the output lines and set COMPREPLY.
4. and so on for each of the other type of handler (-W, -G, etc). I think handling -F, -C, -W, and -A should cover a majority of the cases.
5. for the default handler, there's a special case of it returning 124 which means we must restart from step 1 to see if the handler has defined `complete` for our wanted command.

Comment: Look at the completion for e.g. `sudo`.

Comment: That's what I did before posting this question. I thought that `_sudo` didn't do the above, but after a second look it turns out it does. Thanks!